# Cast String field to datetime64[ns] in parquet file using pandas-on-spark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark-pandas

My input is parquet file with I need to recast as below:

```
df=spark.read.parquet("input.parquet")
psdf=df.to_pandas_on_spark()

psdf['reCasted'] = psdf['col1'].astype('float64')
psdf['reCasted'] = psdf['col2'].astype('int32')
psdf['reCasted'] = psdf['col3'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

In the above code I am able to convert `col1` into `float64` and `col2` into `int32`. But when I try to convert `col3` into `datetime64[ns]`, I am getting the recasted value as `NaT`. Note that `col3` is originally a String which I trying to convert to `datetime64[ns]`

I can do this recasting using Pandas as below:

```
psdf['reCasted'] = pd.to_datetime(psdf['col3'],format='%Y-m-%d%')
```

But I don't want to use Pandas as the process is taking time. I want to use pandas_on_spark only. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

To recast the col3 column from a string to datetime64[ns] using pandas_on_spark, you can utilize the to_timestamp function provided by pandas_on_spark.

Comment: Tried like this : psdf['reCasted'] = ps.to_timestamp(psdf['col3'],format='%Y-m-%d%'). But I am getting "AttributeError: module pyspark.pandas has no attribute to_timestamp"

Comment: psdf['reCasted'] = ps.to_datetime(psdf['col3'],format='%Y-m-%d%') is working. thanks